# How to set <img /> src dynamically in React without throwing a 404 error at render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState('')
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setSrc('someEndPoint.jpg')
  }, [])

  return <img src={apiUrl + src}>
}
```

With this implementation, the component will fetch the `src` at render. But before then, the `img` will throw a 404 by trying to GET the root of the api. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just render it when src is available;

Please try following:

```
return src && <img src={apiUrl + src} />
```